# How to find out if DOMContentLoaded event comes from iframe or not?

Tags: javascript, firefox, event-handling, firefox-addon, dom-events

I am working on a Firefox extension and it uses something like this:

```
function myExt()
{
    this.handleEvent = function (event)
    {
        switch (event.type)
        {
            case "DOMContentLoaded":
            {
                alert('fired');
            }
        }
    }

    window.addEventListener ("DOMContentLoaded", this, false);
}
```

My problem is that the alert gets executed multiple times if the page contents iframes, so what I am looking to do is, using "event" on this.handleEvent **I need to find out if event.target references the top window or the iframe window.**

***How can I do this?***

Comment: Whaaa? DOMContentloaded fires for the iframe *in the parent window*? Weird, never heard of this

Comment: I think it's more like, it fires for the iframe itself, then bubbles up to the document that contains it.

Comment: Yea it has something to do with "event bubbling"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am still doing some tests but it looks like this function does the job:

```
this.isTopLevel = function(event){
    var doc = event.target;
    for(var i = 0; i < gBrowser.browsers.length; i++) {
        if(gBrowser.browsers[i].contentDocument == doc) return true;
    }
    return false;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try checking for event.target.frameElement. If it's undefined then it's the main document, but if it is defined then it's a frame. I can't remember if this is only for frames, though, or if it's for iframes too.

Comment: Thanks that looks as a nice solution, I solved it comparing the event.target with the gBrowser.browsers documents. It seems to work fine that way too.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, `iframe` is weird in that will fire `DOMContentLoaded`. It treats the content as if it were in its own 'window'. Have you tried getting the `event.target`'s parent or `ownerDocument`?

I used [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) on an SVG loaded into an `<object>` tag and I believe that `ownerDocument` gets what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this snippet to filter out iframes:

```
var browser = gBrowser.getBrowserForDocument(event.target);
var pageIsFrame = (event.target instanceof Ci.nsIDOMHTMLDocument &&
  event.target != browser.contentDocument);
if (pageIsFrame) {
  // Not interested in frames.
  return;
}
```

You need Chrome privileges for that.

In the new add-on SDK content scripts (where you don't have Chrome privileges), I'm using this:

```
if (window.frameElement) {
  // This is an iframe.
  //...
}
```

(See MDC doc [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.frameElement) or [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_School/Intercepting_Page_Loads)).